# Left function in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

In table 'Period' there is a column 'Date' ,example data is `FEBRUARY 3,2010`

Now in where condition `Left(Date,3)='Feb'` also gives results,Is the Left function case insensitive?

Comment: Left is not case sensitive, nor is it case insensitive. It's the collation that matters.

Comment: And now that you know how LEFT works you should start storing your dates as date or datetime instead of strings. :)

Comment: I can't rightly fathom the confusion of ideas that would lead to this question about case sensitivity specifically focussing on the `Left` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the collate in your query, for example

```
Declare @YourTable table (Col varchar(25))
Insert Into @YourTable values 
('February'),
('february'),
('FEBRUARY')

Select * 
 From  @YourTable 
 Where left(Col,3) = 'Feb' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

Returns

```
February
```

Conversely, if set to `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`  (insensitive)

You'll get

```
February
february
FEBRUARY
```

Answer (score 0):

You ca also use below query:

```
select * 
from table_name
where left(lower(column_name),3)  = 'feb'
```

EDIT:
if you don't care about case sensitivity and not sure about collation, if collation is CI (case insensitive) then "lower" is not needed however there is no harm to use it as this function seems to be not expensive one.

Comment: If you have a case insensitive collation feb will equal FEB

Comment: @SeanLange, agree, depend what OP actually need, he can use mine solution if doesn't care about case sensitivity or John's if sensitivity is needed.

Comment: What I am saying is that LOWER is a pointless function here unless the collation is case sensitive.